# How can I change the /media folder to other one

Tags: media

In the system (Ubuntu 16.04) I am using, serveral development sdk folders created previously by different people are put under /media folder. roughly I know /media fold is being used for special purpose by the system, at least the gvfs automounting is using it, Actually I want to get the Ubuntu system to use another folder to play the same funtion as /media does. Is that possible, If so, how can I do that? Please help！

best Regard!
By Bill Z

Comment: You can just rename a folder, however many programs are coded to use `/media/` and won't be fooled by a renamed (or linked) folder & won't touch anything there (I'm thinking of snaps, which have special rules for /media, /mnt etc where I believe anything in your renamed/linked won't be able to be used by any containerized snap)

Comment: my system don't have any thing installed with snap!

Comment: The *snap* was used as an example.... You'll have to check what programs you do have installed, and if any will have issues like my *snap* example.  You gave no specifics (server? desktop? what programs you use, how installed etc..)

Answer (score 1):

You decide where data are stored, not the system.

For many functions, the system creates its own dedicated folders. That is the case with `/media`. The system is configured to mount among others, removable media there.

So do not touch that folder if you do not want to break automatic mounting of external drives. Instead, create a different folder where you can do whatever you want. That actually could be a subfolder under `/media`: creating your own custom folder under `/media` will not in any way interfere with the system. Changing the `/media` folder itself, however, will.

So leave the `/media` folder alone. To specifically answer your question: **you cannot change the /media folder to other one**, unless you have deep knowledge about the linux system and can handle for all effects such change would have.

Comment: I found the locate database ignore /media folder recursively, as its content is a dynamic one.

Comment: @BillZhao The locate cache is only periodically updated. Running a "sudo updatedb" will reveal the current contents. mlocate is not anymore installed by default on recent Ubuntu versions (possibly since the current 20.10). On systems with SSD, `find` is also fast enough for practical purposes. `locate` remains usefull on systems with slower traditional spinning hard drives.